# Why does this float overflow

Tags: python, floating-point, python-3.5

I understand the floating point numbers only have a limited precision. But I don't understand why a 64bit float (which I assume these are) will overflow with these values:

```
ipdb> (-1e+10 - 0.01)
-10000000000.01  # 0.01 still visible
ipdb> (-1e+20 - 0.01)
-1e+20  # 0.01 is gone, I assume because of floating point precision
```

This might be relevant:

```
ipdb> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

Note that the actual problem I want to solve is normalizing these values to be between 0 and 1 `[-1.3229999632394e+32, 15000.0, -11.432000160217285, -11.321000099182129]`

Comment: I don't see any overflow. Can you clarify? What are you seeing, and what do you expect to see (and why)?

Comment: What overflow are you speaking of?

Comment: The problem is the 0.01 part is gone in the second calculation. (I've added some comments in the example)

Comment: That's not overflow, that's the limited precision of floating point numbers that you said you understand.

Comment: The same goes when printing this without the scientific notations:

```ipdb> '{n:.5f}'.format(n=(-1e+10 - 0.01))
'-10000000000.01000'
ipdb> '{n:.5f}'.format(n=(-1e+20 - 0.01))
'-100000000000000000000.00000'```

Comment: IEEE 754 binary64 floats (which is almost certainly what Python is using here) have 15-17 decimal digits of precision, depending on how you count. You're asking for a change in the 22nd most significant figure.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, I am confusing precision with overflow than! Is there any way of having increased precision?

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/

Comment: You can use a package that provides high-precision binary floating-point, (like gmpy2). But in my experience, it's rarely needed - it's much more common that what you actually need to do is reformulate your approach to not need more than 16 digits of precision.

Comment: do you REALLY need to add 0.01 to 1e+20 ??

Comment: No, see the note, basically we use log scores for ranking, and need a fallback for log(0), currently we use `-1e+32`, but that causes these problems down the line. So we could use something less extreme as a fallback for log(0), but I don't know what a good value would be (this was the smallest float a protobuf could store)

Comment: The logical fallback for log(0) is negative infinity. If that does not work in your use-case, you need to think about the meaning and significance of a zero score, and probably handle it separately.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, using -inf is a bit more work since we need to handle it separately in some cases, but that will be the most elegant solution probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not often necessary to have this kind of precision, but there are packages that do it for you, for example [Bigfloat](http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/)

```
from bigfloat import *

print (-1e+20 - 0.01) == -1e20

with precision(64*2):
    a = BigFloat.exact(-1e+20)
    b = BigFloat.exact(0.01)
    print a == b
```

Will output:

```
True
False
```

Scaling also works

from bigfloat import precision, BigFloat

```
listy = [-1.3229999632394e+32, 15000.0, -11.432000160217285, -11.321000099182129]
m = min(listy) #do this before import, as BigFloat
M = max(listy)

with precision(128):
    scale = lambda x : (x-BigFloat(m)) / (BigFloat(M)-BigFloat(m))
    print [ scale(BigFloat(i)) for i in listy ]
```